# Finish execution if first query returns a value Node.js Express.js mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Before starting, please mind that i have been searching this over 2+ hours, the answer will be simple i know but i couldnt get it to work . i am new to express node mongodb,

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {  
      res.status(err.status); // or use err.statusCode instead 
      res.send(err.message);
    }
    var usernameGiven = req.body.usernameGiven;
    //Select the database
    var dbo = db.db("notifellow");
    //run the query
    var query = { username: usernameGiven , friends: []};

    dbo.collection("users").findOne({ username: usernameGiven}, function(err, result) {
      if (err){
        res.status(err.status); // or use err.statusCode instead 
        res.send(err.message);
        console.log("Query Error Occured!");
      }
      else {
        if (result) {
          //Send the response
          res.send("EXISTS");
      //I WOULD LIKE TO EXIT IF THIS LINE EXECUTES
        }
      }
    });

    dbo.collection("users").insertOne(query, function(err, result) {
      if (err){
        res.status(err.status); // or use err.statusCode instead 
        res.send(err.message);
        console.log("Query Error Occured!");
      }
      else {
        if (result) {
          //Send the response
          res.send("CREATED 201");
        } else {
          res.send("Failed to insert");
        }
      }
    });
    db.close();
  });
```

my goal is to check if an user doesnt exists with given username, i would like to insert that to the DB.
i would like to exit if my query finds an match and arrange such that insertOne wont execute. please enlighten me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are not using the async/await syntax you will have to nest the calls to MongoDB, so they execute in series. You can also use a module like `async` to achieve this.

```js
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {  
      res.status(err.status); // or use err.statusCode instead 
      res.send(err.message);
    }
    var usernameGiven = req.body.usernameGiven;
    //Select the database
    var dbo = db.db("notifellow");
    //run the query
    var query = { username: usernameGiven , friends: []};

    dbo.collection("users").findOne({ username: usernameGiven}, function(err, result) {
      if (err){
        res.status(err.status); // or use err.statusCode instead 
        db.close();
        console.log("Query Error Occured!");
        return res.send(err.message);
      }
      
      if (result) {
        db.close();      
        return res.send("EXISTS");
      }
        
      dbo.collection("users").insertOne(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err){
          res.status(err.status); // or use err.statusCode instead 
          db.close();
          console.log("Query Error Occured!");
          return res.send(err.message);
        }

        db.close();

        if (result) {
          return res.send("CREATED 201");
        }

        res.send("Failed to insert");
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: You are welcome. Do some research about async/await so your code look better!

Comment: i will bro :)))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dbo.collection("users").findOne({ username: usernameGiven}, function(err, result) {
  if (err){
    //put the error logic
  }
  else {
    if (result) {
      //Send the response

      return result;
  }
  else{
        // if above if block fails it means that  user  does not exist
        //put the insert logic
    }
});
```

Comment: `findOne` does not return an error if no document is found